# How to draw single horizontal bar chart divided by limits into equal colored rectangles in Vega

Tags: visualization, vega

I have a Vega chart for which I need to draw horizontal bar based on the field Value divided by limits into equal segments and the color of each segment rectangle is different based on Limit field.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 50,
  "padding": 5,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"Limit": "limit1", "Value": 68635283},
        {"Limit": "limit2", "Value": 155875411},
        {"Limit": "limit3", "Value": 248701010},
        {"Limit": "limit4", "Value": 335999594},
        {"Limit": "limit5", "Value": 429748288}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "signals": [
    {"name": "rectWidth", "value": 100},
    {"name": "rectHeight", "value": 40},
    {"name": "rectY", "value": 0}
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "scalex",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "Value"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": "category",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "Limit"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "scalex"},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "color"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "scalex", "field": "Value"},
          "y": {"signal": "rectY"},
          "width": {"signal": "rectWidth"},
          "height": {"signal": "rectHeight"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "Limit"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The interval limits are :
min= 0
,max= 519 605 603

The interval size is : (max - min)/no Of Limits
The expected result is something like that :
[image]

I need to add later the slider for each limit, I found this example useful [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vega-demo-forked-hjt92s?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A99%2C6-109%2C7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example I show you how to get the min and max aggregates and also how to filter on a range. I think the filter is all you need now.
Mark as answered if this helps you.
Please provide a real example so we can help you.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"value": 1, "color": "#fae6c3"},
      {"value": 2, "color": "#f0cd91"},
      {"value": 3, "color": "#ecb95f"},
      {"value": 4, "color": "#e6a532"},
      {"value": 5, "color": "#dc8c2d"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"joinaggregate": [{"op": "min", "field": "value", "as": "minVal"}]},
    {"joinaggregate": [{"op": "max", "field": "value", "as": "maxVal"}]},
    {"filter": "datum.value >= 2 && datum.value <= 4"}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {"x": {"field": "value"}, "color": {"field": "color"}}
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with desired output .